# Linux - How to copy a output of a command into clipboard

Tags: linux, terminal, clipboard

I'm tired of going on internet just to check up my public ip, so I've created a ip.run file :)

That's what is stored in that file:

```
dig TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com | awk -F'"' '{ print $2}'
cat ip.run | xclip
```

I run it with ./ip.run command and I successfuly get my public ip from google servers, but it is not copied to clipboard yet.. So, what I want to achive, is to copy the output of dig command into clipboard automatically.. But ofcourse what I've done so far doesn't work... I really need help on this one :P Thank you so much!

Comment: `dig TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com | awk -F'"' '{ print $2}' | xclip` should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

In X11 you have multiple 'clipboards'.

If you select text with the mouse, you can paste that selection by using the middle mouse button.

Ctrl+c is another clipboard.

See xclip(1):

```
-selection specify which X selection to use, 
                   options are "primary" to use XA_PRIMARY (default), 
                    "secondary" for XA_SECONDARY or "clipboard" for XA_CLIPBOARD
```

Try the middle button after your command. Or use `xclip -selection clipboard` and then ctrl+v

With this you can do:

```
dig TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com | awk -F'"' '{ print $2}' | xclip
```

Then "mniddle button mousclick" in your target

OR

```
dig TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com | awk -F'"' '{ print $2}' | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Then got to your target and hit CTRL+V to paste the clipboard.

Comment: I like your idea, but we need to somehow save the output, which is shown in terminal. So it is logical that "cat ip.run | xclip" won't work, of course. If we manage to make it work with your idea, that would be just perfect!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve? I have the impression that you want to do things a little bit too complicated. 

Do you want to:
A) Save the output of your "dig....|awk" command (i.e. The ipaddress) to a file? Then that would be: "dig ... | awk.... >my_ip.txt"
B) Have the output of the command (the IP-address) in (on of) the clipoard. Then: See above and undestand the "xclip -selection" argument. Just try it out...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend storing the value in an environment variable. The following works for the Korn shell. If you use bash you'll have to modify it. Your command:

```
$ dig TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com | awk -F'"' '{ print $2}'
24.62.111.99
Do this:
$ export MY_VARIABLE=`dig TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com | awk -F'"' '{ print $2}'`
$ print $MY_VARIABLE
24.62.111.99
```

Notice the back quotes `` enclosing your command.

Comment: How can I run this? I tried with ./ip.run but it gives me "line 1: command not found; line2: command not found; error.

Comment: Let's say your shell script "ip.run" is as follows:

    $ cat ip.run
    #!/bin/bash
    dig TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com | awk -F'"' '{ print $2}'

Modify it as follows:

    $ cat ip.run
    #!/bin/bash
    export MYVAR=\`dig TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com | awk -F'"' '{ print $2}'\`

Now, within your shell script, you have the variable MYVAR available containing the output of the dig command chain. You can do whatever you want with it in that shell script.

Comment: It just occurred to me that you might want to have the value in the clipboard because you want to do something with it outside the script. The problem is that when you run a script it is run in a subshell, and when the subshell exits any variables assigned in the subshell are lost. I've seen some discussion of using temporary files, although I don't recommend this.

Comment: Actually, I'm gonna use this value(ip) only in terminal, so it is okay, if variable get lost when I close the shell..